# Bluemix - Cloudant node.js: Error when calling API

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have a node.js app to call an API. The API works well on the first call, but on the second call, it returns this error message:

```
404 Not Found: Requested route ('abc.mybluemix.net') does not exist.
```

Please help review the app.js function:

```
app.js
    app.get('/abc/:provider_id/staffs', function(request, response) {

        console.log("Get method invoked.. ")

        db = cloudant.use(dbCredentials.dbStaff);
        //db = cloudant.use("staffs");
        var docList = [];
        db.list(function(err, body) {
            if (!err) {
                var len = body.rows.length;
                console.log('total # of docs -> '+len);
                if(len == 0) {
                    // error
                } else {
                    var i = 0;
                    body.rows.forEach(function(document) {
                        db.search('allstaff', 'allstaff_index', {q:"provider_id:"+request.params.provider_id}, function(err, doc) {
                            if (!err) {
                                if(doc['_attachments']) {
                                    // todo
                                } else {
                                    var responseDataStaff    = createResponseDataStaffs(
                                                                            doc.rows[i].fields.id,
                                                                            doc.rows[i].fields.provider_id,
                                                                                doc.rows[i].fields.firstname,
                                                                                doc.rows[i].fields.lastname,
                                                                            doc.rows[i].fields.avatar,
                                                                            doc.rows[i].fields.email,
                                                                                doc.rows[i].fields.mobile,
                                                                            doc.rows[i].fields.address,
                                                                                doc.rows[i].fields.username,
                                                                                doc.rows[i].fields.lastlogin,
                                                                            doc.rows[i].fields.lastlogout


                                                                        );
                                }
                                docList.push(responseDataStaff);
                                i++;
                                if(i >=  doc.rows.length ) {
                                    response.write(JSON.stringify(docList));
                                    console.log('ending response...');
                                    response.end();
                                }
                            } else {
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        });

                    });

                }

            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

and log file:
[image]

Comment: What does the logs say ?

Comment: @yashpandey: I just added the log file. Please help preview. Tks

Comment: Not able to read full logs , can you take  a full snapshot ?

Comment: @yashpandey: please see again. the first call API is sucessfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get 404 on the second time is because your app crashed.
Debug it locally before you push to Bluemix.

To debug locally you need to have VCAP_SERVICES defined for your app:

Open a terminal and type cf env

Copy the content of VCAP_SERVICES to a local file (e.g. VCAP_SERVICES.json)

Create a new file next to app.js (e.g. debugApp.js) with this content

```
if(!process.env.VCAP_SERVICES){
 process.env.VCAP_SERVICES = JSON.stringify(require("./VCAP_Services.json"));
 }
 require('./app.js');
```

Then run `node debugApp.js`

Comment: tks so much...let me try :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here but it looks bad

1. You're calling db.list to get a list of all your documents - fair enough
2. You then iterate through each document in the list to give a variable 'document' which you never use
3. You then issue a search request to Cloudant for each document you retrieved in the list. These search requests will be executed in parallel because they are started in a for loop. All of the search requests are identical and do not contain anything about the document you fetched.

I'm guessing that this isn't what you intended to do.